# Finding elements in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list in a list.

I want to find whether it contains an item of interest.

`For example: L=[['READ',[A,B],'2'],['WRITE',[C,D],'2']]`

Now, I have a string, `str=READ`, I want to iterate over the two lists, including the sub lists to find whether such an element is present. Is there a way to do it without resorting to using indexes?

I do not want to use indexing because there is no guarantee of the list length remaining same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided there are no loops in the data stucture being searched this is a simple recursive problem:

```
def find(x, L):
    return x in L or any(find(x, sublist)
                         for sublist in L
                         if isinstance(sublist, list))
```

if instead there can be loops in the data structure then you must guard against entering infinite recursion

```
def find(x, L, seen=None):
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    if id(L) in seen:
        # Avoid infinite recursion
        return False
    seen.add(id(L))
    return x in L or any(find(x, sublist, seen)
                         for sublist in L
                         if isinstance(sublist, list))
```

Comment: How can I see if the element is in it or not? It `returns <generator object <genexpr> at somecharacters>` always...

Comment: @GM: You must have done some typos when copying the functions. They work in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: No I've copied and pasted it.  Then typed `find('A',L)` and this return `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10dc7ab90>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the video!! I think is something related to my distribution with Canopy it return that but I've just tried from terminal and it works perfectly [see Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHLiW-olh6A&feature=youtu.be)!I don't know what say...Thanks!

Comment: @GM: the problem is `any` that in Canopy environment is replaced with a version from numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Using a common flattening function:

```
import collections
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el
```

You can flatten the list and then check if READ is in it.

```
>>> 'READ' in flatten(L)
True
```

Comment: This is a good method. But I don't want to use anything complicated. Check out the answer I have accepted, that was exactly what I wanted.